# How to read outlook emails from a specific outlook folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I'm trying to read all outlook emails from a specific outlook folder and my current code is doing it by using a default number assigned to each folder in Outlook. For example, I learned "6" means "Inbox" and "16" means "Drafts" and I'm using 16 here to loop all the emails in my Drafts folder.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(16)
messages = inbox.Items
```

But I want to change my source folder. I want to create a new folder in my outlook and use that as my source folder. However, I can't tell what the default number is for the new folder I created, which means I don't know what number should go into outlook.GetDefaultFolder() to use the new folder. Is there any way I can check the default number of the new folder in Outlook? Or can I use the name of the folder, instead of number?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

**Your answer on your question:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders

If you use this code: inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(16)
It will take your Drafts folder and you can start from their on. Also "GetDefaultFolder" means go tot the default account e-mail. If you have more than one e-mail accounts in you outlook it always takes your main account.

**My advice**
Use this code instead:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Getnamespace("MAPI")

# Select your e-mail account you want to use
account = outlook.Folders("youremail@account.com")

# this is the main folder that is under your account like Inbox, Draft, sent items, Outbox, etc
inbox = account.Folders['Inbox']

# Now you can select the subfolder inside the main folder
inboxsubfolder = inbox.Folders['Sub_folder_inside_Inbox_Folder']
print(inboxsubfolder) #The result should be the name of the folder.

#Read first E-mail
messages = inboxsubfolder.Items #or inbox.Items 
message = messages.GetLast()
print(message) #You get the last message inside this folder.
```

Now you are within the "Inbox" folder of your selected account. I you want  you can go to subfolders etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the folder is in the default store, you can drill down starting with root folder:

```
folder = outlook.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().Folders.Item("Inbox").Folders.Item("Inbox subfolder")
```

If the folder is in a non-default store, you need to find the store by name first:

```
folder = outlook.Stores.Item("otheruser@domain.demo").GetRootFolder().Folders.Item("Inbox").Folders.Item("Inbox subfolder")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module

You can search match and expand patterns

```
import glob
print(glob.glob("/home/adam/*.txt"))
```

and get a list of the file types you are looking for:

```
['/home/adam/file234.txt', '/home/adam/file235.txt', '/home/adam/file236.txt', .... ]
```